# How to use gcloud filter?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

This command works to limit regions to the ones I specify

`gcloud compute networks subnets list --network=MYNW --filter="region:(us-west1 us-west2)"`

But when I use this, it fails. Of course, I can iterate over the items in an array but was wondering if we can get this to work

`gcloud compute networks subnets delete MYNW --filter="region:(us-west1 us-west2)"`

Comment: The command flag `--filter` is not supported by `subnets delete`. Compare the documentation for [list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/subnets/list) and [delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/subnets/delete). The first specifies that `--filter` is supported, the second does not even mention filters.

Comment: You are right John. I noticed that but was hoping at least someone would have a fix/workaround for it. Its quite annoying iterating over a list to perform this task.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to provide an expression to delete subnets? Using shell scripts is very easy for tasks like this. Languages like Python make this very easy. You can submit a feature request: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Its just that if you are trying to delete 10 subnets, it is more efficient to run one command to delete all of them vs performing a for loop and running the same command 10 times (with different values). Just my thought.

Comment: @souser Did you get the answer for your post? If so, please post it as an answer so other community members can see it too

Comment: @JamesS  unfortunately no solution. Workaround is to iterate over the list but that means running the command several times.

Comment: @souser I understand, but as John stated, the features/command flag that you are looking for isn't supported at the moment, so the workaround would be through shell scripts. For now, you may submit a feature request through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and hopefully it gets added in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @JohnHanley:

The command flag `--filter` is not supported by `subnets delete`. Compare the documentation for [list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/subnets/list) and [delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/subnets/delete). The first specifies that `--filter` is supported, the second does not even mention filters.

If you want to provide an expression to delete subnets, using shell scripts like Python make this very easy. Since the command flags that you are looking for are currently a limitation at the moment, kindly raise a feature request through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so it can be considered in the future.